# Soft question: Why use optimization algorithms instead of calculus methods?

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-optimization

I know that some functions are multivariate and therefore take a long time to compute zeros for the gradient, and then test for minima, maxima, etc. However, some optimization algorithms are not tractable either, and numerically they are never analytical and they don't give an analytic solution. So what is the purpose of not simply using the analytical methods we have from calculus eg solving gradient zeros vs possibly incorrect and at best approximate optimization algorithms?

Comment: For a general nonlinear function, finding the zeros of the gradient is also not possible analytically. So either you use a numerical method to optimize the function, or you derive the gradient and then use a numerical method to compute its zeros; either way, you get a numerical approximation. Best to cut out the middleman and optimize the function directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason to use *any* numerical method is that you might not have an explicit analytical solution to the problem you're trying to solve.  In fact, you might be able to prove (as with the [three body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)) that *no* analytical solution involving elementary functions exists.  Thus approximate methods (numerical or perturbation-based) are the best we can do, and when applied correctly (this is important), they usually provide answers with high degree of accuracy.

An elementary example of this issue (as mentioned by several comments) is finding roots of polynomials of high degree.  As was [proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) in the early 19th century, there is no explicit formula for the roots of a polynomial of degree 5 or higher.  Thus if your derivative consists of such functions, solving $f^\prime(x) = 0$ is only possible using a numerical technique.

For a more complicated example, many times the function you are trying to optimize does not even have an explicit functional form.  In calculus, you learn how to optimize functions like "$f(x) = x\exp(-x)$".  Here you have an explicit formula for which you can take derivatives and solve $f^\prime = 0$.  But many times you don't have this - what you have is something like "let $\boldsymbol{x}_0$ be the initial condition for a nonlinear system of differential equations
$$
\dot{\boldsymbol{x}} = f(\boldsymbol{x})\\
\boldsymbol{x}(0) = \boldsymbol{x}_0
$$  Define $f(\boldsymbol{x}_0) = g(\boldsymbol{x}(1))$, i.e. run the system until $t=1$, then evaluate some function $g()$ there.  This function will almost *never* have an explicit functional form.  Thus if you wanted to compute

$$
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}_0} f(\boldsymbol{x}_0),
$$  you would almost certainly be forced to use a numerical method.

I will say that there are methods that are a hybrid of numerical and exact/algebraic.  For instance, you can use something like a Newton's method (which would usually require Hessian matrices) together with [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).  Automatic differentiation treats a computational algorithm *like* an explicit formula and then takes explicit derivatives of it using a (highly sophisticated) version of the chain rule.

Comment: You can get more fundamental, roots of fifth degree polynomials and optimization of $f(x)=e^x+sin(x)$. No need to go to optimal control etc.

Comment: Fair enough.  I like to emphasize that many interesting functions are not given by formulas.  Many students come away from calculus thinking all functions can be written down explicitly in terms of elementary functions, which is misleading.

Comment: Yes, textbooks or homework will pose questions that are symbolically solvable. It is easy to miss that those problems are the exception, almost any modification will lead to problems with no symbolic solution. But those are only posed in numerics courses.

Comment: True; i almost forgot that Galois theory can prove that higher degree polynomials are impossible to solve analytically in general, and this poses a problem

Comment: I also didn't quite understand your system of equations. What did you mean run until $t$ = 1?